# SELECT DISTINCT on one column, with multiple columns returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database with 20 columns but on my select I only want the following 3 columns:

Task
UniqueID
MessageID (unique identifier)

How can I get all the distinct UniqueID while returning the above 3 columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(UniqueID), Task, MessageID
```

doesn't seem to work? :/

Comment: Yes it is possible, the question is the following: if the Task and MessageID columns stores different values for a specific UniqueID, which value do you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is not a function :

```
SELECT DISTINCT UniqueID
     , Task
     , MessageID 
FROM table
```

But this will return all unique *rows* not unique `UniqueID`. If you want to retrieve only rows with different `UniqueID` you should use the `GROUP BY` clause and aggregate functions with fields `Task` and `MessageID` to manipulate grouped data.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:-

```
SELECT task,
       UniqueID,
       MessageID,
FROM   (SELECT task,
               UniqueID,
               MessageID,
               Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY MessageID) rn
        FROM   TableName) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```